# Control the dashed border stroke length and distance between strokes

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

Is it possible to control the length and distance between dashed border strokes in CSS?

This example below displays differently between browsers:

```css
div {
  border: dashed 4px #000;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>I have a dashed border!</div>
```

Big differences: IE 11 / Firefox / Chrome

[image: IE 11 border][image: Firefox Border][image: Chrome border]

Are there any methods that can provide greater control of the dashed borders appearance?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Css render is browser specific and I don't know any fine tuning on it, you should work with images as recommended by Ham.
Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-style-properties

Answer (score 218):

The native dashed border property value does not offer control over the dashes themselves... so bring on the `border-image` property!

## Brew your own border with `border-image`

**Compatibility**: It offers [great browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) (IE 11 and all modern browsers). A normal border can be set as a fallback for older browsers.

### Let's create these

These borders will display exactly the same cross-browser!

[image: Goal example] [image: Goal example with wider gaps]

### Step 1 - Create a suitable image

This example is 15 pixels wide by 15 pixels high and the gaps are currently 5px wide.  It is a .png with transparency.

This is what it looks like in photoshop when zoomed in:

[image: Example Border Image Background Blown Up]

This is what it looks like to scale:

[image: Example Border Image Background Actual Size]

#### Controlling gap and stroke length

To create wider / shorter gaps or strokes, widen / shorten the gaps or strokes in the image.

Here is an image with wider 10px gaps:

[image: Larger gaps] correctly scaled = [image: Larger gaps to scale]

### Step 2 - Create the CSS — this example requires 4 basic steps

1. Define the [border-image-source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-source):

   ```
    border-image-source:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdVc.png");
   ```
2. **Optional** - Define the [border-image-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-width):

   ```
    border-image-width: 1;
   ```

   The default value is 1. It can also be set with a pixel value, percentage value, or as another multiple (1x, 2x, 3x etc). This overrides any `border-width` set.
3. Define the [border-image-slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice):

In this example, the thickness of the images top, right, bottom and left borders is 2px, and there is no gap outside of them, so our slice value is 2:

```
    border-image-slice: 2;
```

The slices look like this, 2 pixels from the top, right, bottom and left:

[image: Slices example]

4. Define the [border-image-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-repeat):

In this example, we want the pattern to repeat itself evenly around our div. So we choose:

```
    border-image-repeat: round;
```

**Writing shorthand**

The properties above can be set individually, or in shorthand using [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image):

```
border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdVc.png") 2 round;
```

### Complete example

Note: `border-style` must be set to a value such as `solid` or `dashed` as the initial border style is `none`. Alternatively, you can add a fallback border, such as `border: dashed 4px #000` in this example, non-supporting browsers will receive this border.

```css
.bordered {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  /* Optional: 
     A normal dashed border can be set as a fallback, particularly if older browsers need to be supported. Notes:
     - the 4px width here is overwritten with any border-image-width value
     - a border-image-width can be omitted if it is the same value as the dashed border width
  */
  border: dashed 4px #000;/*optional*/

  /* the initial value of border-style is "none", so it must be set to a different value for the border-image to show*/
  border-style: dashed;

  /* Individual border image properties */
  border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdVc.png");
  border-image-slice: 2;
  border-image-repeat: round;

  /* or use the shorthand border-image */
  border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdVc.png") 2 round;
}


/*The border image of this one creates wider gaps*/

.largeGaps {
  border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKclP.png");
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">This is bordered!</div>

<div class="bordered largeGaps">This is bordered and has larger gaps!</div>
```

Comment: Note that you need to specify `border-style: solid` (or something similar) if you omit the fallback.

Comment: This solution does not work with 'border-color' attribute

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Of course. If you want other colors you'll need to make another image, with the color you want. `border-color` will _never_ change the color of the border image.

Comment: It doesn't work with border-radius. Do you know of a fix for that?

Comment: @KlevisMiho would depend on what type of border you want. Maybe a background image and `:before` like: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image-source/#aa-border-radius-is-a-no-go or an SVG like the answer below.

Comment: @misterManSam this did the trick https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator/

Comment: This is a bit blurry right?

Answer (score 151):

In addition to the `border-image` property, there are a few other ways to create a dashed border with control over the length of the stroke and the distance between them. They are described below:

### Method 1: Using SVG

We can create the dashed border by using a `path` or a `polygon` element and setting the [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) property. The property takes two parameters where one defines the size of the dash and the other determines the space between them.

**Pros:**

1. SVGs by nature are scalable graphics and can adapt to any container dimensions.
2. Can work very well even if there is a `border-radius` involved. We would just have replace the `path` with a `circle` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087463/dotted-dashed-circle-shapes-using-css-not-rendering-right-in-chrome/30093139#30093139) (or) convert the `path` into a circle.
3. [Browser support for SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5) is pretty good and fallback can be provided using VML for IE8-.

**Cons:**

1. When the dimensions of the container do not change proportionately, the paths tend to scale resulting in a change in size of the dash and the space between them (try hovering on the first box in the snippet). This can be controlled by adding `vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'` (as in the second box) but the browser support for this property is nil in IE.

```css
.dashed-vector {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 10;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* just for demo */

div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover{
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dashed-vector'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 300 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M0,0 300,0 300,100 0,100z' />
  </svg>
  <span>Some content</span>
</div>

<div class='dashed-vector'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 300 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M0,0 300,0 300,100 0,100z' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/>
  </svg>
  <span>Some content</span>
</div>
```

---

### Method 2: Using Gradients

We can use multiple `linear-gradient` background images and position them appropriately to create a dashed border effect. This can also be done with a `repeating-linear-gradient` but there is not much improvement because of using a repeating gradient as we need each gradient to repeat in only one direction.

```css
.dashed-gradient{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-position: left top, left bottom, left top, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 20px 3px, 20px 3px, 3px 20px, 3px 20px;
}

.dashed-repeating-gradient {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, blue 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%), repeating-linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, blue 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 0%, blue 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 0%, blue 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  background-position: left top, left bottom, left top, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 20px 3px, 20px 3px, 3px 20px, 3px 20px;
}

/* just for demo */

div {
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='dashed-gradient'>Some content</div>
<div class='dashed-repeating-gradient'>Some content</div>
```

**Pros:**

1. Scalable and can adapt even if the container's dimensions are dynamic.
2. Does not make use of any extra pseudo-elements which means they can be kept aside for any other potential usage.

**Cons:**

1. [Browser support for linear gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) is comparatively lower and this is a no-go if you want to support IE 9-. Even libraries like CSS3 PIE do not support creation of gradient patterns in IE8-.
2. Cannot be used when `border-radius` is involved because backgrounds don't curve based on `border-radius`. They get clipped instead.

---

### Method 3: Box Shadows

We can create a small bar (in the shape of the dash) using pseudo-elements and then create multiple `box-shadow` versions of it to create a border like in the below snippet.

If the dash is a square shape then a single pseudo-element would be enough but if it is a rectangle, we would need one pseudo-element for the top + bottom borders and another for left + right borders. This is because the height and width for the dash on the top border will be different from that on the left.

**Pros:**

1. The dimensions of the dash is controllable by changing the dimensions of the pseudo-element. The spacing is controllable by modifying the space between each shadow.
2. A very unique effect can be produced by adding a different color for each box shadow.

**Cons:**

1. Since we have to manually set the dimensions of the dash and the spacing, this approach is no good when the dimensions of the parent box is dynamic.
2. IE8 and lower do not [support box shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow). However, this can be overcome by using libraries like CSS3 PIE.
3. Can be used with `border-radius` but positioning them would be very tricky with having to find points on a circle (and possibly even `transform`).

```css
.dashed-box-shadow{
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dashed-box-shadow:before{ /* for border top and bottom */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 3px; /* height of the border top and bottom */
  width: 10px; /* width of the border top and bottom */
  background: blue; /* border color */
  box-shadow: 20px 0px 0px blue, 40px 0px 0px blue, 60px 0px 0px blue, 80px 0px 0px blue, 100px 0px 0px blue, /* top border */
    0px 110px 0px blue, 20px 110px 0px blue, 40px 110px 0px blue, 60px 110px 0px blue, 80px 110px 0px blue, 100px 110px 0px blue; /* bottom border */
}
.dashed-box-shadow:after{ /* for border left and right */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 10px; /* height of the border left and right */
  width: 3px; /* width of the border left and right */
  background: blue; /* border color */
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 0px blue, 0px 40px 0px blue, 0px 60px 0px blue, 0px 80px 0px blue, 0px 100px 0px blue, /* left border */
    110px 0px 0px blue, 110px 20px 0px blue, 110px 40px 0px blue, 110px 60px 0px blue, 110px 80px 0px blue, 110px 100px 0px blue; /* right border */
}
```

```html
<div class='dashed-box-shadow'>Some content</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to use the svg solution I advise adding `pointer-events:none` to svg inorder to be able to interact with the content.

Comment: While fairly impractical for many border situations, I had not thought to use box shadows like this previously. This opens the possibility of a lot of really cool effects. +1 just for the inspiration.

Answer (score 51):

There's a cool tool made by [@kovart](https://github.com/kovart) called the [dashed border generator](https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator).

It uses an svg as a background image to allow setting the stroke dash array you desire, and is pretty convenient.

You would then simply use it as the background property on your element in place of the border:

```css
div {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='6%2c 14' stroke-dashoffset='0' stroke-linecap='square'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is a simple, easy and quick solution

Answer (score 38):

**Update**
Thanks to kovart for this great tool try it
https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator/

[image: a tool to generate dashed custom borders]

my answer was:

I just recently had the same problem.
I have made this work around, hope it will help someone.

HTML + tailwind

```
<div class="dashed-border h-14 w-full relative rounded-lg">
    <div class="w-full h-full rounded-lg bg-page z-10 relative">
        Content goes here...
    <div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dashed-border::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #333 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 16px;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.dashed-border::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 4px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Wow that border generator was a amazing one! Thanks for sharing

Comment: honestly the best answer. Other solutions work until border-radius is involved, so you need to solve it with JS or a preprocessor which what this site is.

Answer (score 28):

Short one: No, it's not. You will have to work with images instead.

Comment: this answer is outdated as of 2018

Comment: @WilliamHampshire I would go with this technique https://youtu.be/vs34f9FiHps?t=779 but check accepted answer, you might like other solutions better

Comment: @godblessstrawberry Thanks!! But's that's using SVG so still not using just css...

Comment: @WilliamHampshire there is box-shadow solution in the thread I meant answer by Harry

Comment: @godblessstrawberry Have you tried the solution? The solution drawn the dashed line segment by segment. It's just a POC and useless in practice!

Comment: @YuJianrong yeah, I agree, personally I would use SVG solution (SVG embedded in CSS background-image property)

Answer (score 12):

Stroke length depends on stroke width. You can increase length by increasing width and hide part of border by inner element.

**EDIT:** added `pointer-events: none;` thanks to benJ.

```
.thin {
    background: #F4FFF3;
    border: 2px dashed #3FA535;  
    position: relative;
}

.thin:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #F4FFF3;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ksf9zoLh/

Comment: But this way you will unable to click contents of original element because "after" pseudoelement will cover it. So the best way is use SVG.

Comment: You can add `pointer-events: none` to prevent the overlay issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
.outline {
    outline: 48px dashed #d5fb62;
    outline-offset: -4px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

if overflow hidden not problem else outline 4 instead 48.

```
<div class="outline"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I think I've just found the definitive solution to this problem with the use of `clip-path` property. Basically all there is to add a dashed border then mask the excess.

The `clip-path` property also supports rounded corners so you can match it up with the `border-radius` and have custom dashed borders and rounded corners!

```css
.demo {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: inset(0 round 30px 0 30px 0);
}

.demo::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
  top: -7px;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  border: 8px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 37px 0 37px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

You could do this directly on the `div` itself of course without using the `::after` pseudo element. But this would mean you have to clip into the `div` and it would end up smaller than it's initial size.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had the same problem.

I managed to solve it with two absolutely positioned divs carrying the border (one for horizontal and one for vertical), and then transforming them.
The outer box just needs to be relatively positioned.

```
<div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute absolute--fill overflow-hidden">
        <div class="absolute absolute--fill b--dashed b--red"
            style="
                border-width: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
                transform: scaleX(2);
        "></div>
        <div class="absolute absolute--fill b--dashed b--red"
            style="
                border-width: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
                transform: scaleY(2);
        "></div>
    </div>

    <div> {{Box content goes here}} </div>
</div>
```

Note: i used tachyons in this example, but i guess the classes are kind of self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

This will make an orange and gray border using the class="myclass" on the div.

```
.myclass {
    outline:dashed darkorange  12px;
    border:solid slategray  14px;
    outline-offset:-14px;
}
```

Comment: By "provide greater control of the dashed borders appearance", the OP (Original Poster) means that he wants to control the length of each dash, as stated at the beginning of the question. Sorry for any confusion.