# Number input with character border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the layout below but all my attempts have failed. As you can see in the code snippet below, it just doesn't look right on desktop and on iPads.

[image]

Basically I have one number input field where visitors input their four digit post code to get the results.

I don't want to create four different inputs and give them borders to get the desired layout.

Can this be done using just one input box?

```css
input {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eff1f1, #eff1f1 25px, white 10px, white 40px, #eff1f1 40px, #eff1f1 65px, white 10px, white 80px, #eff1f1 80px, #eff1f1 105px, white 10px, white 120px, #eff1f1 120px, #eff1f1 145px, white 10px, white 160px);
    width: 180px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 29px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px auto -5px auto;
    color: transparent !important;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666;
}
```

```html
<input type="number"></input>
```

Comment: Share what you have already tried.

Comment: share your code..

Comment: I've updated the original post with code.

Comment: Looks fine to me - I changed `letter-spacing: 29px;` to `letter-spacing: 27px;` for better spacing but overall looks good

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I feel that there has to be a better solution than background gradient.

Comment: do you want visitor enters four digits one after another by pressing tab key or what? as you said "Can this be done using just one input box?". what do you mean?

Comment: @HouyNarun No, just one input box styled like how it's shown in the screenshot. Users would just continuesly type without pressing the tab key. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @shutupchigo, so basically, your problem is it does not layout neatly and nicely on desktop and iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".input").keyup(function(){
    var len=$(this).val().length;
    if(len==4){
     $(".input").blur(); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
.input{
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  background:transparent;
  border:none;
  font-size:25px;
  letter-spacing:36px;
  text-indent:15px;
}

.input:focus{
  outline:none;
}

.inputbg1,.inputbg2,.inputbg3,.inputbg4{
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  height:44px;
  width:40px;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  border-right:solid 10px #fff;
  border-left:solid 10px #fff;
}

.inputbg1{
left:0px;
}

.inputbg2{
left:50px;
}

.inputbg3{
left:100px;
}

.inputbg4{
left:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<input type="text"  class="input" max-length="4">
<span class="inputbg1"></span>
<span class="inputbg2"></span>
<span class="inputbg3"></span>
<span class="inputbg4"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but when you try to remove digits after entering the last one, it doesn't remove the digits.

Answer (score 1):

If the style layout is your issue, What is about this?

```css
input {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eff1f1, #eff1f1 25px, white 10px, white 40px, #eff1f1 40px, #eff1f1 65px, white 10px, white 80px, #eff1f1 80px, #eff1f1 105px, white 10px, white 120px, #eff1f1 120px, #eff1f1 145px, white 10px, white 160px);
  width: 180px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 29px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px auto -5px auto;
  color: transparent !important;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4">
```

Basically, the layout of yours is almost alright, thought. I just remove outline border to make it looks better. Another side note, `maxlength` is ignore in `input type=number` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome). Please let me know, should this is what you want or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Below solution , similar to the existing.

single input with Validation ,  layout wise a all seperate inputs

```css
.otp_field {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  width: 12.70em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.otp-wrapper, .otp_field {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 48px;
}

.otp-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.otp-wrapper:after {
  content: "—————";
  line-height: .3em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="otp-wrapper">
        <input class="otp_field form-control" type="text"
        inputmode="numeric"
        autocomplete="one-time-code"
        pattern="\d{5}" maxlength="5"
        required>
      </div>
```

Answer from

> [input text with dashed border and stroke length equal to the characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722887/input-text-with-dashed-border-and-stroke-length-equal-to-the-characters)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).