# Dashed border using css gradient

Tags: css

I'm trying to find out how to add a dashed border that will look the same in the latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE10+ browsers. Ordinary `1px dashed #000` doesn't work for me because it's different in all browsers, and `image` doesn't scale.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this by CSS gradient.

It would be cool if there is the possibility to control dash length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control the dashed border stroke length and distance between strokes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes)

Comment: This may also help in understanding how dash + gradient can be produced - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500570/gradient-line-with-dashed-pattern/32501799#32501799 (not sure if you meant a dashed border created *using* gradient or a dashed border *with* gradient)

Comment: Dashed border created with css gradient, will be more accurate next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) for that:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
      -webkit-border-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png') 30;
    -o-border-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png') 30;
    border-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png') 30;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: What about ie10-11? Will it work there? It's important. As i wrote, i dont want to use image, i used to cut an image of single dash in the past, but doent like that solution.

Comment: @Rantiev If you rely on browser default styles, than accept that styles may change depending on browser and OS

Comment: I want to have the same dashed border done using gradient in the browsers list i provided.

Comment: @Rantiev Check this page: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/