# Dashed border top not even

Tags: css

I am trying to add dashed border top on a div using css. I have this:
https://jsfiddle.net/uexma4o6/74/

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 2px dashed #AAA;
}
```

The problem is that first and last dash are little longer than others. I think it's because actual borders on the left and right are included? How can I make all dashes same width? I am looking for solution without using border-image. Thanks.

Comment: do you need it for underlining or realy as a border?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control the dashed border stroke length and distance between strokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes)

Comment: I didn't found answer on that thread. I would like not to use border image.

Comment: The answer was that there was no way to control it. You should use border image instead as that would allow control.

Comment: the best way would be to use an svg as borderimage, maybe a inline svg

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SVG line within your div like -

```
<div>
    <svg width="50" height="2" viewBox="0 0 50 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="#AAA" stroke-dasharray="2" stroke-width="2"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you can adjust the size and width based on your requirement.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 33%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
background-position: top;
background-size: 5px 3px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-right-width: 2px;
```

Comment: not working, can you update jsfiddle with this code working?