# Make a dashed vertical line in css

Tags: html, css

I have the following design for make the layout. I'd like to make that line with CSS and HTML but my way doesn't work.

[image]

I tried with a border and used the property "dashed" with css but the lines appear vertically.

Comment: Repeating linear gradient

Comment: Hi, how can I do that?

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes

Comment: [Polite] Please can you remove the "Blazor" tag from this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use repeating-linear-gradient() function, for example:

Image the syntax of the function in this example like this:
repeating-linear-gradient(item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4)

item 1: Make the gradient starts with the color: white

item 2: Make the color: white go to height 2px

item 3: Start a new color: #CCC from the 2px (continue after the height of the previous color)

item 4: Make the last color (#CCC) ends in 4px . so the the color #CCC start from 2px and go to 4px, so the height of it = 2px , which is the same height of the color: white (item 2)

- so this process repeated until gradient fills the height of the element

Note : You can change the size (height) of the dash by change the px in the function ( in this example it's 2px )

```css
div {
  width: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 2px, #CCC 2px, #CCC 4px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```