# CSS consistent border spacing across browsers

Tags: html, css

I've created a dashed border-left to go around some content, but after testing it across browsers the spacing across each dash is inconsistent. I've done some searching but haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Chrome:

[image: chrome result]

Firefox:

[image: firefox result]

Styling:

```
.border {
border-left: 2px dashed black;
border-radius: 10%/200px
}
```

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try with semicolons in your CSS-definition?

Comment: yes add semicolon

Comment: You might have success with this: [Control the dashed border stroke length and distance between strokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes)

Comment: [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is a popular library that can keep your CSS consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should look into other ways to achieve consistent border style. Check out this one https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator/

> Native CSS properties don't support the customization of border-style. Therefore, we use a trick with an SVG image inside background-image property. The SVG features give us the ability to change the distance between dashed lines, set custom pattern, add dash offset or even change a line cap. Generated SVG image is vector and it fills width and height of elements by 100%, so it doesn't matter what size elements have.