# increase spacing between dashed border for <th> tag of <table>

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I have below codepen as follows
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wu-swzjts

[image]

As you can see the output of codepen, the header tags has dashed border at top and bottom. I am trying to increase the spacing between the dashed borders but unsuccessful. Also, i want to increase the width of each dash here but i am unable to do so.

The current code is as follows

```
-- HTML --
<th colspan="2" key={indx}>

-- CSS --
th {
  padding: 1rem;
}

th[colspan] {
  border-top: 1px dashed black;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

I am trying to do it as a inline styling. I tried the following

```
<th style={{ borderBottom: '1px dashed #000', borderTop: '1px dashed #000', margin: '10px 0' }}>
```

No matter how much i try to add margin: '10px 0', or padding or width and any border-spacing to the th style, i am unable to increase the spacing between each dash and increase width of each dash.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

I am trying to achieve this way
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control the dashed border stroke length and distance between strokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes)

Comment: not possible to control the dash width/spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer would be to abandon trying to use the CSS border settings, which can vary between browsers, and go for total control of the spacing (either relative in relation to the width of the element or absolute in terms e.g. of px units) by using background image of a linear gradient.

Here's an example which uses % sizing, but you may want it to be in say em units in order to get it looking similar for a particular font size.

```css
table thead tr {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vmin;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%), linear-gradient(to right, black 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: 10% 1px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 calc(100% - 1px);
  
}
```

```html
<table><thead><tr><th colspan="2">PROJECT NAME</th><th colspan="2">BUILD</th></tr></thead></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer - I had a thinking error in there previously:

You need to add the padding to the *cells*, not the *row*. To affect only the cells in the table heading row, you would basically write it as follows, since the first row contains the header cells (`th`), all others the regular cells (`td`):

```
th {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

It gets a bit more complicated if you also have `th` cells at other positions (for example all first cells in all rows as headings for the rows). But for a basic function, the above should suffice.

Concerning the question about inline CSS in your comment: Sure, but you'd have to add the `style:padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem>` attribute to *each*  `th`.

Comment: please see my changed answer and the addition to it.

Comment: Hi Johannes- i am not trying to increase spacing between header names and dashed border but i am trying to increase spacing between the dashed borders itself.

Comment: Hmm - do you mean you don't have collapsed borders, but seperate borders for each cell?

Comment: hi Johannes- i updated the question with how the dashed border i am expecting

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean, and also your codesandbox shows no output... How about answering my previous question?

Comment: Johannes: for e.g. these are two dashed borders - - i am trying to increase spacing between these two. Similarly, trying to increase spacing between all the dashed lines. codepen updated.

Comment: ahh, the dashed border style! I don't think that can be changed, it depends on the browser to render that.